# TCPStore() has the unmatched '}' in format string

Tags: python, pytorch

This project uses visdom but get the error. This problem occurs in torch\distributed\rendezvous.py

```
    python scripts/segmentation_train.py --data_dir ./data/TrainDataset --out_dir ./outdata/direction --image_size 256 --num_channels 128 --class_cond False --num_res_blocks 2 --num_heads 1 --learn_sigma True --use_scale_shift_norm False --attention_resolutions 16 --diffusion_steps 1000 --noise_schedule linear --rescale_learned_sigmas False --rescale_timesteps False --lr 1e-4 --batch_size 8

 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\python_work\MedSegDiff-master\scripts\segmentation_train.py", line 117, in <module>
    main()

  File "D:\python_work\MedSegDiff-master\scripts\segmentation_train.py", line 26, in main
    dist_util.setup_dist(args)

  File "D:\python_work\MedSegDiff-master\.\guided_diffusion\dist_util.py", line 46, in setup_dist
    dist.init_process_group(backend=backend, init_method="env://")

  File "C:\Users\laapn\anaconda3\envs\py39torch\lib\site-packages\torch\distributed\distributed_c10d.py", line 754, in init_process_group
    store, rank, world_size = next(rendezvous_iterator)

  File "C:\Users\laapn\anaconda3\envs\py39torch\lib\site-packages\torch\distributed\rendezvous.py", line 246, in _env_rendezvous_handler
    store = _create_c10d_store(master_addr, master_port, rank, world_size, timeout)

  File "C:\Users\laapn\anaconda3\envs\py39torch\lib\site-packages\torch\distributed\rendezvous.py", line 177, in _create_c10d_store
    return TCPStore(
    
    RuntimeError: unmatched '}' in format string
```

But in this code I can't find '{}' to solve the problem

```
if _torchelastic_use_agent_store():
    attempt = os.environ["TORCHELASTIC_RESTART_COUNT"]
    tcp_store = TCPStore(hostname, port, world_size, False, timeout)
    return PrefixStore(f"/worker/attempt_{attempt}", tcp_store)
else:
    start_daemon = rank == 0
    return TCPStore(
        hostname, port, world_size, start_daemon, timeout, multi_tenant=True
    )
```

I try to print (hostname, port, world_size, start_daemon, timeout), But it doesn't look like they have a problem.

Comment: Please [edit] your post to include the full error traceback. The last line is not enough

Comment: Post [mre], i.e. incl. your code and full traceback. The snippet you show is from [`pytorch`](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/6871665a973b33aedd0376294645e217978d1495/torch/distributed/rendezvous.py#L177)