# how to resolve the error message: return TCPStore( ) RuntimeError: unmatched '}' in format string

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, runtime-error, stable-diffusion

I've been trying to run the code from this GitHub repository: [improved-diffusion](https://github.com/openai/improved-diffusion) on my computer. In essence, it involves training a denoising diffusion probabilistic model, which has become increasingly popular in recent years and can be used for various image restoration tasks (e.g., image inpainting, super-resolution).

My main goal is to train my own model using the CelebA dataset, which consists of facial images. However, when I execute the command:
`python scripts/image_train.py --data_dir "D:\WeiTsung\improved_diffusion_main\DDPM_train\img_align_celeba"` as specified in the Training part of README of the GitHub repository, I encounter the following error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\WeiTsung\improved_diffusion_main\DDPM_train\scripts\image_train.py", line 87, in <module>
    main()
  File "D:\WeiTsung\improved_diffusion_main\DDPM_train\scripts\image_train.py", line 26, in main
    dist_util.setup_dist()
  File "D:\WeiTsung\improved_diffusion_main\DDPM_train\improved_diffusion\dist_util.py", line 51, in setup_dist
    dist.init_process_group(backend=backend, init_method="env://")
  File "C:\Users\user\anaconda3\envs\DDPM_training_v2\Lib\site-packages\torch\distributed\c10d_logger.py", line 74, in wrapper
    func_return = func(*args, **kwargs)
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\user\anaconda3\envs\DDPM_training_v2\Lib\site-packages\torch\distributed\distributed_c10d.py", line 1145, in init_process_group
    store, rank, world_size = next(rendezvous_iterator)
                              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\user\anaconda3\envs\DDPM_training_v2\Lib\site-packages\torch\distributed\rendezvous.py", line 247, in _env_rendezvous_handler
    store = _create_c10d_store(master_addr, master_port, rank, world_size, timeout)
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\user\anaconda3\envs\DDPM_training_v2\Lib\site-packages\torch\distributed\rendezvous.py", line 178, in _create_c10d_store
    return TCPStore(
           ^^^^^^^^^
RuntimeError: unmatched '}' in format string
```

The parameters passed to the TCPStore(hostname, port, world_size, start_daemon, timeout, multi_tenant=True) function are as follows:

```
hostname=140.117.172.120
port=2021 (The value varies each time when I execute python scripts/image_train.py --data_dir "D:\WeiTsung\improved_diffusion_main\DDPM_train\img_align_celeba")
world_size=1
start_daemon=True
timeout=0:30:00
```

The images below show the packages and their versions installed in my Anaconda environment used for run the GitHub code (Because there are many installed packages, so I split the packages list into two images):
[please click here to check one part of the installed packages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KoWwJ.png)

[please click here to check the another part of the installed packages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gseWi.png)

My computer has two GeForce RTX4070 12GB GPUs
When I run `print(th.cuda.device_count())`, it returns 2, and when I run `print(th.cuda.is_available())`, it returns True. Hence, I think the GPUs are accessible.
However, I am unsure about the cause of the above error message that prevents successful execution.

I want to let the GitHub code (model) successfully trained with my GPUs, otherwise, the training time will be very long.

I just tried to modify the pytorch and cuda version, because I thought this is just a version incompatibility problem, however, no matter what versions I installed, the error still appears.

Comment: the error is clear:  `RuntimeError: unmatched '}' in format string` so go to that line and close open the `{`...

Comment: @D.L there is no unmatched '{' or unmatched '}' in the torch\distributed\rendezvous.py, line 178, and variables: hostname, port, world_size, start_daemon and timeout all don't contain '{' or '}'

my problem is very similar to: https://stackoverflow.com/q/75875014/23028843 , but there is still no answer